# MySQL create store function syntax issue

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-functions

This is a database on AWS. l connected to it with MySQL workbench.
Engine version:5.7.22
"declare @isvalid int" will trigger an syntax error saying "declare is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting :"

```
delimiter |
create function validate(id int) returns integer deterministic
begin 
    set @isvalid = 0;
    while @isvalid = 0 do
    if (select count(triggerman) from test where triggerman = id)=0
            then
                set @isvalid = 1;
            else
                set id = id + 1;
            end if;
    end while;
    return id;
end
|
delimi
```

ter;

21:20:38    create function validate(id int) returns integer deterministic begin      set @isvalid = 0  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3    0.031 sec

Comment: Your syntax should be all right.  The logic, I'm not so sure about.

Comment: the logic is fine. l tested it in a stored procedure. lt does what l want, but it kept telling me l got syntax error when l try to create a stored function.

Comment: If this is a correct copy&paste of your code: the last `delimiter;` requires a space, `delimiter ;`. The rest of your code (at least the syntax) looks fine.

Comment: `AWS RDS` or `AWS Aurora` is used as a database?

Comment: AWS RDS is used as the database here